# Get .NET solution active configuration and platform using command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Can I get `.NET` solution active configuration and platform using command line only? I would like the external process to check the `.sln` file and specify if `Debug` or `Release` is selected and which platform is chosen.

Comment: Given that the active configuration/platform is either the default (e.g. Debug|AnyCPU) or else the one specified on the commandline this is a bit of a chicken-or-egg problem.

Comment: I specified my own Platforms and Configurations (unified app for smart TVs).

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things done when building a solution is calling the ValidateSolutionConfiguration target, which also happens to print out the configuration. Example:

```
> msbuild /nologo /t:ValidateSolutionConfiguration my.sln
...
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Win32".
...
```

useful enough, now it's just a matter of parsing the output using some grep-like tool. Here's for example how to output just configuration and platform using powershell:

```
PS > (msbuild .\ig\ig.sln /t:ValidateSolutionConfiguration) |
      Select-String 'Building solution configuration "(\w+)\|(\w+)"' |
      %{ $_.matches[ 0 ].Groups[ 1, 2 ].Value }
Debug
Win32
```